# jquery .load links not working

Tags: jquery, html, load

I use jquery load method as a alternative for Iframe to load html content to div inside my index.html(home) and i got static navigation bar which contains a link on it. but it looks like doesn't working anymore upon clicking a first link. I also got an log on console saying:

***Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.***

PS: begineer level :)

here's my code

HTML LINK:

```
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li id="tolink1"><a href="#">SAMPLE 1</a></li>
        <li id="tolink2"><a href="#">SAMPLE 2/a> </li>
        <li id="tolink3"><a href="#">SAMPLE 3</a></li>
        <li id="tolink4"><a href="#">SAMPLE 4</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Jquery:

```
//#loadcontent is the id of the div
$(document).on('click', '#tolink1', function(e){
    $("#loadContent").load('http://localhost/impex/SAMPLE1.html');

});

$(document).on('click', '#tolink2', function(e){
    $("#loadContent").load('http://localhost/impex/SAMPLE2.html');

});

$(document).on('click', '#tolink3', function(e){
    $("#loadContent").load('http://localhost/impex/SAMPLE3.html');

});

$(document).on('click', '#tolink4', function(e){
    $("#loadContent").load('http://localhost/impex/SAMPLE4.html');

});
```

Comment: Why are you using `e.preventDefault()`?

Comment: oppss! i just tried something on my code but I already removed.

Comment: Is it working now?

Comment: yes, the links work but only at first time after that I can't click any link anymore. I also notice that my url above my browser is something like localhost/impex/#

Comment: I used jquery to load external html page into div main body that included links. Jquery with .click(function()) and .load() behavior could not activate these links. However, by using "click to link" "$(document).on('click', '#tolink4', function(e){ }", it successfully activated these links. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your html to this:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li id="tolink1"><a href="javascript:void(0)">SAMPLE 1</a></li>
        <li id="tolink2"><a href="javascript:void(0)">SAMPLE 2/a> </li>
        <li id="tolink3"><a href="javascript:void(0)">SAMPLE 3</a></li>
        <li id="tolink4"><a href="javascript:void(0)">SAMPLE 4</a></li>
 </ul>
```

then try it!

Comment: already tried. the same problem only the # remove on the url, link only works at the first time. I also getting a warning on my console saying: Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Comment: that warning is not so important, put console.log() in your `click` function and check if it is called.

Comment: also tell where is `loadContent` div in your html page?

Comment: I have that loadContent div inside my index.html to load an html file.

Comment: after this `ul.dropdown-menu`?

Comment: no. after the navigation bar div which is located below my navigation ba.

Comment: is there any ids like `tolink1`,`tolink2` in your loaded html files(http://localhost/impex/SAMPLE1.html)?

Comment: No. ids `tolink1`, `tolink2` is a link inside the my navigation bar. my navigation bar is only located on index.html

Comment: comment the line where you are loading html file and put `alert()` check if its working on clicking multiple times?

Comment: the same it works at the first time cant even click the link and the dropdown wont work.

Comment: there is must be some other operations performed on that click, you haven't provide your whole code so i can't see where the problem resides.